# Add Column with p values - speed efficient

Tags: r, performance

I have a large table with several thousand values for which I would like to compute the p-values using `binom.test`. As an example:

```
test <- data.frame("a" = c(4,8,8,4), "b" = c(2,3,8,0))
```

to add a third column called `"pval"` I use:

```
test$pval <- apply(test, 1, function(x)  binom.test(x[2],x[1],p=0.05)$p.value)
```

This works fine for a small test sample such as above, however when I try to use this for my actual dataset the speed is way too slow. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you give us some more information about your large dataset? For instance, do you expect there to be a lot of duplicated rows in `test`?

Answer (score 3):

If you are just using the p-value, and always using two-sided tests, then simply extract that part of the code from the existing `binom.test` function.

```
simple.binom.test <- function(x, n)
{
  p <- 0.5
  relErr <- 1 + 1e-07
  d <- dbinom(x, n, p)
  m <- n * p
  if (x == m) 1 else if (x < m) {
    i <- seq.int(from = ceiling(m), to = n)
    y <- sum(dbinom(i, n, p) <= d * relErr)
    pbinom(x, n, p) + pbinom(n - y, n, p, lower.tail = FALSE)
  } else {
    i <- seq.int(from = 0, to = floor(m))
    y <- sum(dbinom(i, n, p) <= d * relErr)
    pbinom(y - 1, n, p) + pbinom(x - 1, n, p, lower.tail = FALSE)
  }
}
```

Now [test that](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MakeItWorkMakeItRightMakeItFast) it gives the same values as before:

```
library(testthat)
test_that(
  "simple.binom.test works",
  {
    #some test data
    xn_pairs <- subset(
      expand.grid(x = 1:50, n = 1:50),
      n >= x
    )

    #test that simple.binom.test and binom.test give the same answer for each row.
    with(
      xn_pairs,
      invisible(
        mapply(
          function(x, n)
          {
            expect_equal(
              simple.binom.test(x, n),
              binom.test(x, n)$p.value
            )
          },
          x,
          n
        )
      )
    )
  }
)
```

Now see how fast it is:

```
xn_pairs <- subset(
    expand.grid(x = 1:50, n = 1:50),
    n >= x
  )    
system.time(
  with(
    xn_pairs,
    mapply(
      function(x, n)
      {
        binom.test(x, n)$p.value
      },
      x,
      n
    )
  )
)
##    user  system elapsed 
##    0.52    0.00    0.52
system.time(
  with(
    xn_pairs,
    mapply(
      function(x, n)
      {
        simple.binom.test(x, n)
      },
      x,
      n
    )
  )
)
##    user  system elapsed
##    0.09    0.00    0.09
```

A five-fold speed up.